# Checking for a specific value in an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist

I need to determine if a element in my ArrayList has a specific value.  This is the current way I am trying.

```
 public static boolean hasDwgNamedReference(Object valueDWG){ 
  boolean b = false; 
  String dwgName = "dwg_";
  if(valueDWG == null){
     b = false;
  }
  else {
     String checkNamedRef = Arrays.toString((Object[]) valueDWG).substring(1, 5);
     System.out.println("checkNamedRef " + checkNamedRef + "\n");   
     if(checkNamedRef.equals(dwgName)){
           b = true; 
        }
  }
  return b;
 }// end hasDwgNamedReference
```

I am pretty sure that the issue is with the

```
 String checkNamedRef = Arrays.toString((Object[]) valueDWG).substring(1, 5);
```

Do you think I need to increment the ArrayList and check each element?

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you do not need to include the first "if" statement.  b is already false, so setting it to false again is unnecessary.

If you use the Arrays.toString() method on an object, you may get the *identity* of the object, or the address in memory that it holds.  If you try to compare to checkNamedRef via an equals method, you may be comparing an address and a string, which would never give you the true you are looking for.